# Add specific word at predefined positions automatically in UITextField in custom TableViewCell

Tags: uitableview, uitextfield

I am working on project 
There is a phone number textField. I want to add phone number like (123)123-1234 
As user click on textField it automatically add "("and after three numbers automatically add ")"then after three numbers add "-"then after 4 number text field did not allow any further addition of numbers

here is my code i am trying to use

but there is one problem when i try to del the numbers it stuck at "-"

```
 - (BOOL)textField:(UITextField*)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range
replacementString: (NSString*) string {
```

if (textField == _phoneNumberTextFieldPersonalData) {
    NSString *text = [textField.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range
                                                             withString: string];

    if (text.length == 1 ) { //or probably better, check if int
        textField.text = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"(%@", text];
        return NO;
    }
    else if (text.length == 4)
    {
        textField.text = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%@)", text];
        return NO;
    }
    else if (text.length == 8)
    {
        textField.text = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%@-", text];
       return NO;
    }
    else if (text.length >= 14)
    {
        [textField resignFirstResponder];
        return NO;
    }
}
return YES;

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have solved it like this and it works Perfect

simply i added a check with if to check whether i am adding a text or deleting it so it works

```
 -(BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
{
    NSLog(@"string Length %d",string.length);
```

if([string length]>0)
{
    int ascii=[string characterAtIndex:0];
    if ([_phoneNumberTextFieldPersonalData isEqual:textField]){
        if(ascii>=48&&ascii<=57)
        {
            int length = [self getLength:textField.text];
            NSLog(@"Length  =  %d ",length);

            if(length == 10)
            {
                if(range.length == 0)
                    return NO;
            }

            if(length == 3)
            {
                NSString *num = [self formatNumber:textField.text];
                textField.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"(%@) ",num];
                if(range.length > 0)
                    textField.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[num substringToIndex:3]];
            }
            else if(length == 6)
            {
                NSString *num = [self formatNumber:textField.text];
                //NSLog(@"%@",[num  substringToIndex:3]);
                //NSLog(@"%@",[num substringFromIndex:3]);
                textField.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"(%@) %@-",[num  substringToIndex:3],[num substringFromIndex:3]];
                if(range.length > 0)
                    textField.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"(%@)%@",[num substringToIndex:3],[num substringFromIndex:3]];
            }
            return YES;
        }
        else return NO;
    }
}


return YES;

}

Answer (score 0):

A UITextField can send various notifications which you can find at the end of [UITextField Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITextField_Class/Reference/UITextField.html). By listening to these, you can change the `text` property of the UITextField to behave like you want it to.

To add yourself as an observer for a notification, use

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:observer
                                         selector:@selector(handleTextFieldChange:)
                                             name:UITextFieldTextDidChangeNotification
                                           object:textField]
```

(The arguments are just an example, change them to suit your app.)

Make sure that the observer(usually `self` but can be any object) has a

```
- (void)handleTextFieldChange:(NSNotification *)note {
    //handle the change here
}
```

method. Now, this method is called every time the textField send out a `UITextFieldTextDidChangeNotification` which happens every time the user changes the text in the textField.

Listening to the notifications can help you format the text in the textField as you wish.

**EDIT :** Don't forget to remove yourself as an observer using

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:someObserver 
                                                name:UITextFieldTextDidChangeNotification
                                              object:textField];
```

after you are done. A good place to put this would be in the `dealloc` method of the observer.

Comment: please have a look at the code and let me know what to do now ??

Comment: Well, since I don't know of any way to directly get keystrokes from the onscreen keyboard, the only thing I can think of is to keep track of the textField's length in a property. Then, by comparing it with the new textField's length, you can find out if backspace key has been pressed and act accordingly.